# How to write a particular condition in brackets in active record codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to convert a mysql query in active record codeigniter

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `tb_user_answers` 
WHERE (`question_id` = '1' AND `answer_id` = '2') 
AND  (`question_id` = '2'  AND `answer_id` IN (4, 6)) 
AND (`question_id` = '3' AND `answer_id` IN (8,9,10))
```

I tried but was unable to do that with the below code

```
$this->db->select('user_id');
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 1 && $dropdown['answer_id'] != 0){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id', $dropdown['answer_id']);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 2 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[4,6]);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 3 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[8,9,10]);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 4 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[12,13]);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 5 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[16,17]);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 6 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 0){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id',19);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 7 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 0){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id',22);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 8 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id',24);
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 9 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[26,27]);
  }
}
$query = $this->db->get('tb_user_answers');
```

the output of above query is :

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `tb_user_answers`
WHERE `question_id` = '1'
AND `answer_id` = '2'
AND `question_id` = '2'
AND `answer_id` IN(4, 6)
AND `question_id` = '3'
AND `answer_id` IN(8, 9, 10)
AND `question_id` = '4'
AND `answer_id` IN(12, 13)
AND `question_id` = '5'
AND `answer_id` IN(16, 17)
AND `question_id` = '6'
AND `answer_id` = 19
AND `question_id` = '7'
AND `answer_id` = 22
AND `question_id` = '8'
AND `answer_id` = 24
AND `question_id` = '9'
AND `answer_id` IN(26, 27)
```

Comment: Check the [Query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) section of the docs

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bad approach to the query, not a problem with the coding. Is the main query working fine in database?. It does not make sense using parenthesis to group any and, the result is the same.

You will never find a result where question_id is 1 AND also question_id is 2,

I think your main query will be:

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `tb_user_answers` 
WHERE (`question_id` = '1' AND `answer_id` = '2') 
OR  (`question_id` = '2'  AND `answer_id` IN (4, 6)) 
OR (`question_id` = '3' AND `answer_id` IN (8,9,10))
```